# Change values in one column based on the presence of values in another column, when data are groups based on unique values of grouping variable

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, grouping

I want to change values in one column based on the presence of values in another column, when data are groups based on unique values of grouping variable.

I am using the `mtcars` data. I want to group these data based on the unique values of `cyl`, and then I want to create a variable called `OD_gears` that will display `yes` in every cell of the column associated with a given unique `cyl` value when there is a value of `5` present in any cell in the `gears` column associated with a given unique `cyl` value, and display `no` in cases where those criteria are not met.

In this case, every cell in the `OD_gears` column should have a value of `yes` in it, because at least 1 car associated with the unique `cyl` values has a value of `5` present in the `gears` column.

Is this possible to do? If so, how? Can I use the `dplyr` package and `group_by()` to help accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `if(any(...))` to check the presence for any value in the group.

```
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(OD_gears = if(any(gear == 5)) 'yes' else 'no') %>%
  ungroup

#    mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb OD_gears
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   
# 1  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.62  16.5     0     1     4     4 yes     
# 2  21       6  160    110  3.9   2.88  17.0     0     1     4     4 yes     
# 3  22.8     4  108     93  3.85  2.32  18.6     1     1     4     1 yes     
# 4  21.4     6  258    110  3.08  3.22  19.4     1     0     3     1 yes     
# 5  18.7     8  360    175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2 yes     
# 6  18.1     6  225    105  2.76  3.46  20.2     1     0     3     1 yes     
# 7  14.3     8  360    245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4 yes     
# 8  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2 yes     
# 9  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2 yes     
#10  19.2     6  168.   123  3.92  3.44  18.3     1     0     4     4 yes     
# … with 22 more rows
```

If there are many such conditions to check using `case_when` will be helpful -

```
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl) %>%
  mutate(OD_gears = case_when(any(gear == 5)~ 'yes', 
                              TRUE ~ 'no')) %>%
  ungroup
```